# MVC Render Action copies passed model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc view that uses a hierarchy structure as its model. I pass properties of the model to child actions.

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("SomeAction", "SomeController", Model.Child[0]); }
```

Everything works fine, however I noticed that the default mvc binder copies a value of `Model.Child[0]` using `Activator` and some reflection stuff through the process of constructing the html page. I simply see a different object inside of the "SomeAction" method. I don't want that to happen and keep original objects.

I tried to write a custom binder, check if it's child action and find original object inside of `ControllerContext/ModelBindingContext`. But no luck, I couldn't find the original. Did someone have similar problem, any help will be appreciated?

upd.
I found that when I call `RenderAction` the model is splitted in a `RouteValueDictionary` right away, so no surprise that it has to be recreated before calling underlying controller action. But I don't believe that there is no way to solve it, since in some cases it can potentially lead to performance issues.

Comment: Are you expecting new incoming request to access objects from previously served request?

Comment: Can you provide the code that you tried? When you say " I simply see a different object inside of the "SomeAction" method." what object are you expecting? it sounds like you may be wanting something like this @{ Html.RenderAction("SomeController", "SomeAction", new { paramNameHere = Model.Child[0] } but it's hard to understand from your question what exactly you are wanting.

Comment: No I dont. I want to have only one instance of my models within a single request. For example, 1) request comes 2) create a model (using db or smth) 3) start generating view (simple cshtml page), if that cshtml page refers other page using RenderAction, I see the copy process.

Comment: what are you meaning by '.... if that cshtml page refers other page using RenderAction, I see the copy process'?  Are you saying you have two sections on a page and you want them both to use the same Model, but the second section renders by a 'renderaction' and passes the Model?

Comment: yes. in your case when the second section is about to render. You can set break point inside of default construct of the model type. And you see that constructor gets called.

Comment: Are you using the RenderAction in a for loop? ?